# How to look for a key in a Groovy Map that is of type GStringImpl

Tags: groovy

I have a map like this:

`[FOOBAR:["FOOBAR"], \b(De(\w+))\b:["DELI", "DELEGATE"], SSN:["111-55-4444"]]`

when I iterate the map and print class type of keys, I get this:

```
myMap.each{ k, v -> println "${k.class}:${v}" }
class java.lang.String:[FOOBAR]
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl:[DELI, DELEGATE]
class java.lang.String:[111-55-4444]
```

**Question**

How can I find the key with class GStringImpl?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
myMap[/\b(De(\w+))\b/] == ["DELI", "DELEGATE"]
|            |                 |
|            null              false
[FOOBAR:[FOOBAR], \b(De(\w+))\b:[DELI, DELEGATE], SSN:[111-55-4444]]
```

**UPDATE: Based on comments**

OP wanted to use a variable as key

Comment: Do you want to use 'regular expression` as key?

Comment: ugh. No I don't. However, I deal with regular expressions being inputted as search terms from users. Thats why I have this as a key. I will be calling `toString()` on it to end this madness. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Ok. Is that you like to use a variable in the key? Or you want to assert the value using regex?

Comment: I want to use the variable as the key and just treat it as a string

Comment: @Rao how would I find the key in this example? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9dac929a5f8514ecb6f0f28d1beec1f7

Comment: Can you please check the answer?

Comment: I have commented for your script in gist, please have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it is just trivial, you need to put it in between `(..)`.

change it from:

```
def myMap = [FOOBAR:["FOOBAR"], \b(De(\w+))\b:["DELI", "DELEGATE"], SSN:["111-55-4444"]]
```

to:

```
def userKey = 'key'
def myMap = [FOOBAR:["FOOBAR"], (userKey):["DELI", "DELEGATE"], SSN:["111-55-4444"]]
```

**EDIT:** updating more info.

Groovy accepts key without quotes and with quotes as well. So, if it is object, then needs to be wraped in between (..). It can be any object.

Comment: Yes. so resolved?  Groovy accepts key without quotes. So, if it is object, then needs to be wraped in between `(..)`. It can be any object.